# Antonyms of "Prefer...Over"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, antonyms

Is

"I prefer coffee over tea"

Equivalent to

"I defer tea over coffer"?

Comment: No, [**defer**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/defer) and [**prefer**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/prefer) have different meanings.

Comment: You could say "I reject tea for coffee" or "I turn down tea for coffee" but that is stronger than the sense of "prefer" and doesn't have precisely the same meaning (since you can prefer coffee but still accept tea). Weather Vane has it right.

Comment: @NigelJ I am trying to find antonyms...

Comment: The antonym of 'I prefer coffee over tea' is 'I prefer tea over coffee'.

Comment: @NigelJ Antonym of "prefer"

Comment: Perhaps *decline ... for ...*.